# Continuous conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume we have conditional density of continuous random variable $X_{1}$ with condition that $X_{2}=x_{2}^{0}$ where $x_{2}^{0}$ is some number. Then:
$$f(X_{1}|X_{2}=x_{2}^{0})=\frac{f(X_{1},X_{2}=x_{2}^{0})}{f_2(X_{2}=x_{2}^{0})}$$

My question concerns expression $f_2(X_{2}=x_{2}^{0})$ which equals $0$. 
In my textbook it is explained in such way that $X_{2}=x_{2}^{0}$ such that $x_{2}^{0} \epsilon\ B$ where $B$ is some subset of $R$ in which $f(x_{2})>0$ and $f(x_{2})=0$ for $x$ not in B. So my intuition is that $B$ is some infinitesimal interval around point $x_{2}^{0}$. But then, if $x_{2}^{0}$ is interval not a point, can we write $X_{2}=x_{2}^{0}$ ?

Comment: it cannot be an infinitesimal, and any density function is a real valued function. I think you are mixing probability with density function.

Comment: Density function equals to zero at given point, in this case $x_{2}^0$

Comment: So how is conditional density function defined?

Comment: FWIW, the notations used in this question are atrocious and are probably effectively blocking the OP's understanding.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86492/133995 ok I think that this clarify everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have already pointed out, the conundrum you are facing is because you are confusing probability with probability *density*.

Recall that we have an underlying [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, and $X_2:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. For some event $A \in \mathscr{F}$, we can express the integral relationship between probability density and probability itself as,
$$P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X_2(\omega) \in A\})\ \overset{\text{shorthand}}{=}\ P(X_2 \in A) = \int_A f_2(x_2)dx_2$$

For example, let the event be $A=[-10,12.4]$, then
$$P(X_2 \in [-10,12.4]) = \int_{-10}^{12.4} f_2(x_2)dx_2$$

If the event is $A=\{3\}$ then we might say,
$$P(X_2 \in \{3\}) = \int_{3}^{3} f_2(x_2)dx_2 = 0$$
but this does **not** imply that $f_2(x_2) \equiv 0$ or that $f_2(3)=0$.

It may ease confusion if you only put random variables (capital letters) as arguments of $P$ and only "samples" (really dummy variables, lowercase letters) as arguments of $f$. Saying $f_1(X_1)$ is weird, but $f_1(x_1)$ is not.

Comment: thanks, but I still dont understand one thing. So if $f_{2}(3)$ is undefined, then how is conditional density function defined given occurence $X_{2}=3$

Comment: ok so if $P(X\ \epsilon\ {{3}})=0$ is undefined and/or doesn't imply that $f_2(3)=0$, then what is $f_2(3)$. Value of density function around infinitesimal interval around 3? Then why in most definitions of conditional distributions : "for continuous random variables, the conditional probability density function of Y given the occurrence of the value x of X"

Comment: "And honestly, in [most uncountable $\Omega$ cases](http://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math776/Spring11/776s11lec02_notes.pdf), $\{3\}$ or any singleton set isn't even a member of $\mathscr{F}$, so the answer is really that $P(X_2 \in \{3\})$ is "undefined" since $P:\mathscr{F}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and $\{3\} \not\in \mathscr{F}$." ?? You might want to reformulate. In most cases, $P(X_2\in\{3\})$ is perfectly well defined since $\{3\}$ is in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: ok Did, noone is right in this thread. Could you provide rigorous answer and show proper notation etc.?

Comment: @Did Sorry, will revise that. I was falsely implying $\{3\} \not\in \mathscr{B}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have continuous RVs $X_1,X_2$ with joint density function $ f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ then you can define the conditional joint density given $X_2 = x_2^0$ as $$ f_{X_1|X_2}(x_1|x_2^0) = \frac{f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2^0)}{f_{X_2}(x_2^0)} $$ where $f_{X_2}(x_2)$ is the marginal density of $X_2,$ given by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1.$

This way everything is in terms of densities.

You are right that there's little sense writing $f_2(X_2=x_2^0).$ In general I'm not a fan of the notation you're using cause it confuses random variables with the variables corresponding to them in density functions.

One notation I've seen that is like what your book is talking about is to write the joint density function as $P(X_1\in dx_1,X_2\in dx_2).$ In this notation $dx_1$ refers to an infinitessimal interval around $x_1$ and similarly for $x_2.$ This describes pretty well what a density function is.

Comment: Is such definition of condistional density correct? $P(X\ \epsilon\ dx | Y\ \epsilon\ dy^0)= P(X\  \epsilon\ dx, Y\  \epsilon\ dy^0)/P(Y\  \epsilon\ dy^0) $

Comment: @mokebe I think so. In this notation, these express 'true probabilities' so it's just Bayes' rule.

Comment: @mokebe . Sorry I don't really have a goto probability book that explains densities. It's notoriously tough (I was guilty above of omitting the fact that the 'true probability' requires you to 'multiply the density by $dx$'. Really, it's best understood as the derivative of the CDF, which is a true probability.) I used to be tasked with teaching upper level physics undergrads basic probability theory, and they'd be horribly confused by PDFs until I'd say 'it's just like the wave function squared in quantum mechanics' at which point they immediately got it.